# Are questions about joomla relevant?

Tags: discussion, suitable-question

Until the [Joomla answers proposal](http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/34294/joomla-answers) is accepted (if ever; I've been waiting a while ...), which is the best place to ask Joomla-related questions? Here or Stackoverflow? Does it depend on whether or not the questions involves programming? Have I just answered my own question? ;-)

Answer (score 3):

Your initial estimate is probably accurate, though there's no harm in asking.

If your question concerns using existing Joomla features or plugins and (beyond configuration) leaving `.php` files as they are, Webmasters should be the most appropriate place to ask.

Questions about coding for Joomla or modifying existing code are probably a better fit for [StackOverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/), though if you're looking for the *theory* behind modifications to reduce barriers to search engine indexing, Webmasters may be a good place to inquire and if you are looking for theory behind modifications to improve the user experience I would highly recommend the [User Experience SE](https://ux.stackexchange.com/).